# Font does not change - python3/tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, fonts

Consider the following [example](https://www.delftstack.com/tutorial/tkinter-tutorial/tkinter-label/):

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont  


app = tk.Tk()
labelExample1 = tk.Label(app, text="Customized Label 1", font=("Times", 20))
labelExample2 = tk.Label(app, text="Customized Label 2", 
                         font=("Times", 20, "italic"))

labelFont3 = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=20, weight=tkFont.BOLD,
                         underline=1)
labelExample3 = tk.Label(app, text="Customized Label 3", 
                         font=labelFont3)
labelExample1.pack()
labelExample2.pack()
labelExample3.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

If run this code in jupyter notebook (os:manjaro/linux, python 3.7.2) i get the following output:

[image]

Does someone of you understand, why the font is not changing?

Comment: In python 3.7,windows 10,It will show me the right font.

Comment: That's weird...

Comment: It worked for me... there might be some other issue